# Model.fit_generator throwing a Run time error :

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Training a CNN using Keras, even though I did model.compile, `keras. fit_generator` throws a runtime error saying to do compile my model before using `fit`.

```
Error: 
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\..\Desktop\venvpy36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
Found 468 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 86 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/../Desktop/miscfiles/template_classifier_cnn.py", line 75, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_generator)
  File "C:\Users\..\Desktop\venvpy36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\Desktop\venvpy36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\..\Desktop\venvpy36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 40, in fit_generator
    model._make_train_function()
  File "C:\Users\..\Desktop\venvpy36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 496, in _make_train_function
    raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

tried different optimizers, losses. 
tried building model without function.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Adam

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1000)


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=False
)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))


    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=Adam(0.001),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = build_model()


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/images/template/cnn_train',
        target_size=(256,256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/images/template/cnn_validate',
        target_size=(256,256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
#model.summary()

model.fit_generator(train_generator)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign input shape for your model, I think that is what it missing. Because in your `Sequential()` model you have not assigned input.

Here in your code `model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))`, for the first layer you have to assign `input_shape`.